# Writing code for cookies (and cream) using Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm working on an assignment where I have to write cookies using the values entered through the form and I can't figure out how to get the selected value from the the dropdown menu to save as a cookie.

Javascript

```
    /* this function attachs the event handler under both event models */
    function addEvent(object, evName, fnName, cap) {
        if (object.attachEvent)
            object.attachEvent("on" + evName, fnName);
        else if (object.addEventListener)
            object.addEventListener(evName, fnName, cap);
    }



    function writeCookie(cName, cValue, expDate, cPath, cDomain, cSecure) {
      if (cName && cValue != "") {
         var cString = cName + "=" + escape(cValue);
         if (expDate) 
            cString += ";expires=" + expDate.toGMTString();

         if (cPath) cString += ";path=" + cPath;
         if (cDomain) cString += ";domain=" + cDomain;
         if (cSecure) cString += ";secure";


         document.cookie = cString;
      }
    }

    function saveMailingInfo() {
      var expire = new Date();
      expire.setFullYear(expire.getFullYear() + 1);
      var allFields = document.mailingForm.elements;
      for (var i  = 0; i < allFields.length; i++) {
        if (allFields[i].type == "text") {
          writeCookie(allFields[i].id, allFields[i].value, expire);
        }
        if (allFields[i].nodename == "SELECT") {
          writeCookie(allFields[i].id, allFields[i].selectedIndex, expire);
        }
        if (allFields [i].type == "radio" || allFields[i].type == "checkbox") {
      writeCookie(allFields[i].id, allFields[i].checked, expire);
    }
      }
      alert("Registration data saved");
    }

    addEvent(window, "load", initPage, false);

    function initPage(){
      document.getElementById("sbutton").onclick = saveMailingInfo;
      document.getElementById("favoriteCake").selectedIndex = retrieveCookie("favoriteCake");
    }
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <!-- DW6 -->
    <head>
    <!-- 



    -->
    <title>Cakes by Emily</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
       <script type="text/javascript" src="cakeForm.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body >
    <div class="head" id="header">
      <p><img src="cake.jpg" alt="cake picture" /><img src="logo.gif" alt="Cakes by Emily" width="400" height="125" /></p>
      <div class="links" id="navigation">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Cakes</a>
        <a href="#">Pastries</a>
        <a href="#">Pies</a>
        <a href="#">Mailing List</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mainContent">
    <p>Enter your info to be added to our email list with reminders about getting that birthday 
    cake you want! Remember at Cakes by Emily, we aim to make every birthday the best!</p>
    <form name="mailingForm" >
     <table>
      <tr>
       <td>
      First:

       </td>
       <td> <input type="text" name="firstName"  id="firstName"><BR>
      </td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
      Last: 
       </td>
       <td><input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" ><BR>
      </td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
      E-Mail: 

       </td>
       <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" ><BR>
      </td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
      Birthday (mm/dd/yyyy): 

       </td>
       <td><input type="text" name="birthday" id="birthday" ><BR>
      </td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
      Favorite Cake: 

       </td>
       <td>
        <select id="favoriteCake">
         <option value="ButterCream">Butter Cream</option>
         <option value="Chocolate">Chocolate</option>
         <option value="Vanilla">Vanilla</option>
         <option value="RedVelvet">Red Velvet</option>
       </select><BR>
      </td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
      Frequency of Emails: 

       </td>
       <td><input type="radio" name="frequency" id="frequency1" >Email me monthly<BR>
           <input type="radio" name="frequency" id="frequency2" >Email me quarterly<BR>
           <input type="radio" name="frequency" id="frequency3" >Email me near my birthday<BR>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" id="sbutton" name="sbutton"  value="Join our mailing List" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset the form" />
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the selected item in an HTML `select`, use:

```
var cake = document.getElementById("favoriteCake");
var cakeValue = cake.options[cake.selectedIndex].value;
```

I also can't help but notice that most of your `if` statements are taking advantage of the optional curly braces when the branch contains only one statement:

```
    if (object.attachEvent)
        object.attachEvent("on" + evName, fnName);
    else if (object.addEventListener)
        object.addEventListener(evName, fnName, cap);
```

Here is a good example of why you shouldn't do this:

```
    if (cPath) cString += ";path=" + cPath;
```

This makes it look like if `cPath` is `true`, then the code that follows on the same line will be executed, but `path=" + cPath;` will ALWAYS be executed because when you omit the curly braces, you are telling the JavaScript runtime that only the first statement that follows the test or the `else` should be executed when code enters that branch.

This is an EXTREMELY BAD practice that will eventually lead to bugs in your program.  ALWAYS surround your branch code with curly braces:

```
    if (object.attachEvent){
        object.attachEvent("on" + evName, fnName);
    } else if (object.addEventListener) {
        object.addEventListener(evName, fnName, cap);
    }
```

And:

```
    if (cPath) { 
         cString += ";
         path=" + cPath;
    }
```

Lastly, with your cross-browser event-wiring function:

```
/* this function attachs the event handler under both event models */
function addEvent(object, evName, fnName, cap) {
    if (object.attachEvent)
        object.attachEvent("on" + evName, fnName);
    else if (object.addEventListener)
        object.addEventListener(evName, fnName, cap);
}
```

You should, not only include the curly-braces, but you can increase performance by switching the test order. Since `attachEvent` is only for IE 8 and less, it is going to be the rare scenario that your test is true, but you test for it every time. If you switch the sequence, you will rarely ever have to run the else code, whereas, right now, you have to run the test code and the else code most of the time. Lastly, you only need an `else`, not an `else if` because if one of the event models is not supported, then the other one is - you don't need to test for it.

```
function addEvent(object, evName, fnName, cap) {
    if (object.addEventListener){
        object.addEventListener(evName, fnName, cap);
    } else {
        object.attachEvent("on" + evName, fnName);
    }          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can get the selected Item using the selected Index value property.

```
var cake = document.getElementById("favoriteCake");
var selectedCake = cake.options[cake.selectedIndex].value;
```

> One way to store it in a cookie is :

```
document.cookie = "selected_cake="+selectedCake;
```